# Vector Iterators Incompatible

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a class with a std::vector data member e.g.

```
class foo{
public:

const std::vector<int> getVec(){return myVec;} //other stuff omitted

private:
std::vector<int> myVec;

};
```

Now at some part of my main code I am trying to iterate through the vector like this:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = myFoo.getVec().begin();
while( i != myFoo.getVec().end())
{
   //do stuff
   ++i;
}
```

The moment I reach this loop, I get the aforementioned error.

Comment: You are returning a copy of the vector, probably you want to return a `const std::vector<int>&`

Comment: Do you really want to return a *copy* of your vector?

Comment: Please don't return const values from functions, as it inhibits C++11 move semantics.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal the error is aforementioned in the title I presume.

Comment: @Seth: I never saw an error that simply reads, on its own, "Vector Iterators Incompatible"

Comment: @Tomalak : It's a VC++ runtime assertion message.

Comment: @ildjarn: Nothing else at all is output?

Comment: @Tomalak : Not that I recall (other than the usual assertion stacktrace info), but then I don't see that assertion very often myself. ;-]

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The reason you are getting this, is that the iterators are from two (or more) different copies of myVec. You are returning a copy of the vector with each call to `myFoo.getVec()`. So the iterators are *incompatible*.

Some solutions:

Return a const reference to the `std::vector<int>` :

```
const std::vector<int> & getVec(){return myVec;} //other stuff omitted
```

Another solution, probably preferable would be to get a local copy of the vector and use this to get your iterators:

```
const std::vector<int> myCopy = myFoo.getVec();
std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = myCopy.begin();
while(i != myCopy.end())
{
  //do stuff
  ++i;
}
```

Also +1 for not `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 11):

You are returning a copy of the vector. Because you are returning by value - your call to begin() and end() are for completely different vectors. You need to return a const & to it.

```
const std::vector<int> &getVec(){return myVec;}
```

I would do this slightly differently though. I'd make the class act a little like a standard container

```
class Data
{
   public:
      typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator const_iterator;

      const_iterator begin() const { return myVec.begin(); }
      const_iterator end() const { return myVec.end(); }
};

Data::const_iterator i=myFoo.begin();

while(i != myFoo.end())
{
//
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Another cause of the MSVC STL debug assertion "vector iterators incompatible" is operating on an invalidated iterator.

I.e. `v.erase(i)`, and then compare `i != v.end()` the erase invalidates `i` and so it cannot be used in a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you always return another copy of the vector. Use a reference:

```
const std::vector<int>& getVec(){return myVec;} //other stuff omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

well, I don't think vector copy could be the only cause, that seems to be too obivious to me.

in my case I just find that corrupted stack, heap, uninteneded changes could also result in this failure, and it will in fact hiding the underlying reason. in my case, I changed to use indexer to iterate through and find the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason why this assert can trigger is if you would allocate "foo" with 'malloc' instead of 'new', effectively skipping the constructor(s).

It's unlikely to happen to a project developed from scratch in C++, but when converting plain-C code to C++ (replacing a static array[] in some struct with an stl-vector) you might just not realise that dynamic instances of said struct (and the members inside) are not going to have their constructor called - unless you also change 'malloc' to 'new'.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a constant copy of the member vector, not accessing the member vector.

Change this:

```
const std::vector<int> getVec(){return myVec;} //other stuff omitted
```

to this:

```
const std::vector<int> & getVec(){return myVec;} //other stuff omitted
```

To go a little deeper, the iterator you get from this statement:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = myFoo.getVec().begin();
```

is an iterator to the temporary copy of your vector, which goes away after that statement executes, invalidating the iterator.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but your for loop to do stuff should be in a member method of class foo. You generally shouldn't have things outside a class operating on the internal data of a class.

Comment: And it's an invalidate iterator for a _different_ container. Two problems.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
const std::vector<int> getVec(){return myVec;}
```

to

```
const std::vector<int>& getVec(){return myVec;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getVec() function returns a deep copy of the member vector, so the two getVec() calls you make to retrieve iterators get iterators to different containers.  That is, you can't reach getVec().end() from a separate getVec().begin() iterator without invoking undefined behavior.

You can solve this in two ways:

1)  Have getVec return a const reference (that is, const std::vector&) (preferred) or...

2)  Replace the two getVec() calls with one and save the result to a std::vector variable.  Then, use that variable for both calls to begin() and end().  E.g:

```
std::vector<int> v = myFoo.getVec();
std::vector<int>::const_iterator b = v.begin();
std::vector<int>::const_iterator e = v.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning by value - your call to begin() and end() are for completely different vectors. You need to return a const & to it

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer, while it might be correct, is quite terse and difficult to understand. It would be useful if you could expand it; for example if you include some code which uses the change you recommend?

Comment: This exact answer was also used in response to a since-deleted markov generated nonsense question and selected as the answer to said nonsense question.